# Bootstrap-datepicker in modal using bootstrap erases hidden fileds behind when selected

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am having a very weird problem with a page i am making using boostrap3, jquery and bootstrap-datepicker.

I have a dynamic modal (with a form inside it) where the user can select a date. Because the modal is dynamic, i am sending some values from the button to some hidden values inside the modal. (not that it matters if they are inside or outside the modal...)

The problem is when the user clicks on the datepicker, all input text/hidden values are erased and become undefined.

I've set up an example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjWzVr

The code is:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    defaultViewDate: 'today',
    autoclose:true,
    todayHighlight:true
  });
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker('update', new Date());
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker('update');
  var showInField = button.data('showid') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  $('#test').val(showInField)
})
```

And the HTML:

```
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-showid="1">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
      <input data-format="yyyy-mm-dd" type="text"></input>
      <span class="add-on"><i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
  </div>
</div><br>
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="">
```

Using:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2708/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js
```

The reason why i'am doing the 'update' is so that the datepicker has today's date written in the field...codepen doesnt show it...but it works.

Anyone knows why it erases every input field on the page?

Thanks

Comment: THis is because your date format. You need to define it in the JS for the DatePicker too....

Comment: try putting this also: format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Comment: yes sorry i forgot i removed that when i was testing things and then forgot to add it back. its still doing the bug with it though.

Answer (score 0):

I used a different version of bootstrap-datepicker and it works now.
Downvoting my question was a noob thing to do...since i showed an example of the problem and explained what is happening..
Comments provided did not solve the problem...since they could easily test the code in the codepen and see that it was not working.